# Listview inside DialogueFragment unclickable

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, dialog

My app has listview inside dialogueFragment , when user chose item it should `Toast` , in my case items unclickable .

**DialogueFragment**

```
public class HistoryDialogue extends DialogFragment  {

ListView list ;
Cursor c ;
HistoryAdapter adapter ;
Context context ;



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history,null);
    list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

     ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
     c=resolver.query(Contract.SaveRunning.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
     adapter= new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(),c,0);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"keep going ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });

    builder.setView(list);
    return builder.create();

}
```

}

**CursorAdapter**

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context,c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.historylist, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    text.setText(body);

}
```

}

**history.xml**

```
    <ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**historylist.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/delete"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        />
```

Comment: can you post your `R.layout.history` XML code?

Comment: see this link http://www.edumobile.org/android/custom-listview-in-a-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Try to add this line: `android:focusable="false"` in your `ListView` (in `history.xml` ) and Item main layout (in `historylist.xml`) .

Comment: thanx  ya ramy it works

Comment: post this comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:focusable="false"` in your `ListView` (in `history.xml` ) and Item main layout (in `historylist.xml`).

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

and

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your CursorAdapter's bindView:

```
((ViewGroup)row).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

if it isn't enough, add `clickable="false"` to your `historylist.xml`'s Button